# How to extract a specific country boundary data from a GeoPandas dataset

Tags: geopandas, pandas

I want to extract Singapore country boundaries from **'naturalearth_lowres'** dataset from GeoPandas.

```
world_filepath = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
world = gpd.read_file(world_filepath)
world.head()
```

[image]

This is the world boundaries DataFrame from which I want to extract "Singapore" country boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [pandas `loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) should do the trick:

```
singapore = world.loc[world['name'] == 'Singapore'] # get Singapore row
boundaries = singapore['geometry'] # get Singapore geometry
```

Comment: Recently I could not find *'Singapore'* in `'naturalearth_lowres'` dataset...

Comment: @Taras Hi! I know this is a bit late, but for new comers, geopandas DOES NOT have Singapore in their dataset. In fact, the entirety of Singapore's boundaries is within Malaysia. This isn't your fault, it's geopandas' fault. Geopandas also does not have a list of countries on their website, but you can view it from this code: ```import geopandas

                geopandas.read_file(
                    geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")
                )```